# How to get included fields in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have relation like this:

[image: Tables]

Models: I have relations one to many:

```
public class SportClub : EditableEntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

I would like get include current user:

```
var getUserClub = _sportClubRepository.Value
                                      .GetQueryByIncluding(x => x.AppUsers.Where(y => y.Id == 19));
```

But I get an error:

> The Include search path expression must refer to the navigation property defined in the type. Use point paths in the navigation properties of the link, and also use the Select operator for the navigation properties of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: path
>
> Description: Unhandled exception when executing the current web request. Examine the stack trace for more information about this error and the code snippet that caused it.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The Include search path expression must refer to the navigation property defined in the type. Use point paths in the navigation properties of the link, and also use the Select operator for the navigation properties of the collection.
> Parameter name: path
>
> Source error:
>
> 328
>
> Строка 326:            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
> Строка 327:            {
> Строка 328:                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
> Строка 329:            }
> Строка 330:

What am I doing wrong?

What should I do if I would like include fields?

Connect to Db:

```
 private readonly Lazy<IRepository<SportClub>> _sportClubRepository;
    private readonly Lazy<IRepository<AppUser>> _appuserRepository;
```

U***PD:***
I have 3 costum method:

```
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        var query = GetQuery();

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindByIncluding(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        var query = GetQuery().Where(predicate);

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQueryByIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        var query = GetQuery();

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Where is `.GetQueryByIncluding` defined? that's not an EF Core method.

Comment: This is My custom method. I UPD my question

Comment: What is `GetQuery()`? What are you trying to do, anyway? Your code is very complex (feels like unnecessary complex) - maybe show simple code that works; and then when you add some more complex stuff - it stops working. Also, it is very dangerous to have relationship between business object and Identity object. You should use Identity APIs. Finally, Id in AspNetUsers is GUID; not an integer

Comment: GetQuery is `public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery()
        {
            return _dbSet;
        }`

Comment: There are 3 more questions; and I probably have 3 more... Your Object has relationship to `AppUser` - but you don't show its structure. The parameter to `GetQueryByIncluding` is array of stuff; but the argument is a single anonymous function... but I give up. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).